# User permissions error inside container while starting hub docker image

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-grid, selenium-hub

When I run command 
`docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --name selenium-hub selenium/hub`

> docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint selenium-hub (33994db81ec69319f17c2704ba8e7fe8c7544ce33f370ae4af4934db485237f5): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:4444: unexpected error Permission denied.

It's giving me the error. Is there any suggestion to solve this permission problem

Comment: Your user have the permission to bind a port? Try to run your container in root user

Comment: I am doing this from root user